# Passing variable between activities through intent throws NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-intent

Why does this throw NullPointerException ?

In Redeem.java

```
int yourInt = 200;
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Redeem.this, MainActivity.class);
myIntent.putExtra("intVariableName", yourInt);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

In MainActivity.java

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
int score = extras.getInt("intVariableName");
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think in putExtra you just put strings.. Can you try?

Comment: Are you doing this in onCreate?

Comment: Please share your logcat. The code seems okay.

Comment: Obviously `MainActivity` is being started without the "extras" some other way. If you are getting a NPE, it means that `getIntent().getExtras()` is returning `null` indicating that there are no "extras".

Comment: @RafaelaLourenço It didn't work. Yes, I'm doing this in OnCreate. Here's the logcat. I've tried to cut it short to that very moment. https://pastebin.com/2QP2c9yZ Thank You everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String stringScore = extras.getString("intVariableName");
int score = Integer.parseInt(stringScore);
```

Or:

```
int score = intent.getIntExtra("intVariableName", 0);
```

Comment: If OP is getting a `NullPointerException` it means that there is no "extra" `Bundle`, which means that in your first suggestion your code will also throw a `NullPointerException` when executing `extras.getString()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
int yourInt = 200;
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Redeem.this, MainActivity.class);
myIntent.putExtra("intVariableName", String.valueOf(yourInt));
startActivity(myIntent);
```

In MainActivity.java

```
  Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
  int score =Integer.parseInt(extras.getString("intVariableName"));
```

Comment: This will not work. OP has added an `int` "extra". Calling `getString()` will return `null`. In any case, if OP is getting a `NullPointerException` it means that there is no "extra" `Bundle`, which means that your code will also throw a `NullPointerException` when executing `extras.getString()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
getIntent().getIntExtra("intVariableName", 0); //where 0 is default value
```